# What is the position of Lord Vishnu as per Shiva Purana?

Tags: vishnu, shiva-purana

What is the position of Lord Vishnu as per Shiva Purana? Is he given the status of Supreme anywhere in Shiva Purana?

Comment: The Vishnu purana and Bhagavata purana give a better position to Shiva than the Shiva purana gives to Vishnu.

Comment: @LazyLubber you're right. see this https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226407.html chapter, the previous and next chapter. narasimha avatar story ends quite differently after saving prahlada, he goes on to destroy universe and he had to be killed by siva . VP and BP though Vishnu centred don't cross certain level, but SP goes too far. I think it is a result of interpolations.

Comment: @LogTran SP doesn't go too far. It merely follows The Vedas. See Taittiriya Aranyaka 3.15 and its same passages in Shiva Purāna Satarudra Samhita and Linga Purana 1.96

Answer (score 3):

**Lord Vishnu is the Form of Para-Brahman that preseves the world according to the Shiva-Purana**:

> a-kAras cha mahAvijam rajah srastrA chaturmukhah/u-kArah prakritir yonih sattvam pAlayitA harih,ma-karo purusho vijam tamah-samhArako harah// (Vayaviya-samhita, Uttara bhaga, chapter 7).
>
> Meaning : [Of A-U-M], A is the great 'vija' of the fourheaded Brahmaa Who embodies rajo-guna and is the creator, **U is the vija of Hari Who embodies sattva-guna and preserves the world by His prakriti and is the source of everything**, and M is the the vija of Hara Who embodies tamo-guna and is the destroyer by His Paurusha.

In another place of the Shiva-Purana we get

> A-kAro brahma iti Aha U-kAro vishnur uchchyate/Ma-karas tu UmA jneyA prashantam shAshvatam dhruvam// (sanatkumara-samhita)
>
> Meaning : A-kara is Brahmaa, **U-kara is Vishnu** and M-kara is Uma. All are very gentle, Eternal and Truth.

**It is interesting to note that the Vishnu-Purana also says the same**:

> shaktayo yasya devasya brahmaa-vishnu-shivAtmikah/brahmaa-vishnu-shivAh Brahman pradhAnA brahmashaktayah//

Meaning : The  three Principal forms of Brahman in form of Its energy are Brahmaa, Vishnu and Shiva.

> sarga-sthiti-anta-kArinim brahma-vishnu-shivAtmikAm/sa sanjam yAti bhagavAn eka eva janardanah//

Meaning : The three forms of the Same Bhagavan Janardana are Brahmaa, Vsihnu and Shiva for creation-preservation-destruction. Brahman becomes Manifest in these three forms.

Reference: Pranava-Prema-Piyusha, Mahamilan Math, Vol.1, pages 135-141

Comment: The answer is very very misleading. You should give full picture.

Comment: @KrishnaVarna what do you mean?

Comment: @KrishnaVarna You should write answer yourself and stop baseless commenting.